# Best way of creating an Animation?

Tags: android

I want to create a simple animation for my Android Application.
I have a very big Image inside an `ImageView` (1900 x 1200). This Image has small stripes which are transparent so that the background of the View is visible inside of the transparent stripes.

Basically i now need the background to be one color and i need a small white stripe moving from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen. That should be repeated infinitly. You can imagine of it like the front light animation of the black car in Knight Rider.

I tried to implement that using another image in the background which i moved like that:

```
    ObjectAnimator repeatAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.imageViewLightFloatLeft, "y", -Helper.getDisplayHeight(this.getActivity()), Helper.getDisplayHeight(this.getActivity()));
    repeatAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    repeatAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE); 
    repeatAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
    repeatAnimation.start();
```

Unfortunately this is not a good solution because it is lagging really hard. As i mentioned i have an `ImageView` with a big Image (1900 x 1200) in the front and it is slowing down the animation rapidly.

So i need another solution for what i want to do.
How can i implement my animation?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Gradient as the Background of the View and animate that Gradient does the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:centerX="0.5"
        android:centerY="0.5"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:gradientRadius="1000"
        android:startColor="#85E9FF"
        android:type="radial" />

</shape>
```